# Why do i get an Error when trying to change the Text of my TextObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, scripting

I have a TextObject in my script which is attached to my canvas, as seen in the screenshots. Whenevery i try to run it i get that error, I tried many things but can't seem to figure out why this error appears.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;


//TODO: Implement Death screen when health falls to 0 - respawn priority(high)
public class DeathScreen:MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text timeLived;
    public Button replay;
    public Button mainMenu;
    public Button retry;
    

    // ReSharper disable Unity.PerformanceAnalysis
    public void Setup(int timeLivedInSeconds)
    {
        //SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("scenes/main");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/deathScene");
        timeLived.text = "Time Survived: " + timeLivedInSeconds;
        retry.onClick.AddListener(Retry);
        replay.onClick.AddListener(Replay);
        mainMenu.onClick.AddListener(MainMenu);
    }

    
    public void Replay()
    {
        //TODO: call Replay
    }

    public void Retry()
    {
        SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("scenes/death");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("scenes/main");
    }

    public void MainMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("scenes/death");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("scenes/menu");
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

ERROR:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DeathScreen.Setup (System.Int32 timeLivedInSeconds) (at Assets/Scripts/Mechanics/DeathScreen.cs:23)
DeathScreen.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Mechanics/DeathScreen.cs:16)
```

Comment: You start your method with loading a different scene .. so most probably everything else is unloaded and thus all the button instances either don't exist anymore or not yet in the moment you try to access them.

Comment: @derHugo i have a main class in which on death i load this, which should work

Comment: Your death screen instance and everything else is destroyed the moment you for some reason reload that same scene .. of course there will be a new one but the one you called that method on will be gone and along with it all referenced objects as well. I suggest you [Debug your Code with Breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Comment: Why do you think you have to call `SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/deathScene")` when you already are in the deathScene?

Comment: I am not in the death scene, i am in my main, i die. then i switch to the deathScene

Comment: I load the scene, which should load all the variables instantiated in the scene, or is my thinking wrong here. In the debugger it showed all the variables

Comment: Note that also the `UnloadSceneAsync` is completely redundant as Unity anyway unloads everything when using `LoadScene` without using additive loading ;)

Comment: Thats why it's commented out

Comment: Thought at first i needed it

Comment: So in which scene is the DeathScreen script?

Comment: The procedure for the death scene is, i call the death script when my health is below 0, then the death scene is loaded, then it changes the time lived.

Comment: The deathScreen script is in the deathsceen

Comment: but as said its called from annother script

Comment: So as said before the moment you call the `Setup` method you already have to be inside the deathScene ... Then you load the same scene again which destroyed the currently executing instance along with it and also the referenced objects -> you get the exception at right the next line this this very same instance of `timeLived` will not exist anymore since its scene was unloaded and a new scene loaded (it is the same scene asset but a new instance of it)

Comment: "load the same scene again" indeed not, as the death scene isn't loaded when the script is called

Comment: the death scene isnt loaded before so the variables get loaded when         SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/deathScene");
is executed

Comment: If the deathScene isn't loaded then how do you call `Setup` .. a method belonging to `DeathScreen` which you just said is part of the deathScene .... ?? Either way this very instance and all referenced objects are destroyed the moment you call `LoadScene` .. that's all I can tell you .. and the debugger as well

Comment: DeathScreen death = new DeathScreen();
death.Setup(timeLived.Minute);

Comment: Well, the debugger tells me something different indeed

Comment: Oooooo boy ... Please see my comment on one of the answers below ... You **never** use `new` for `MonoBehaviour` you actually should get a warning about it telling you exactly this ...maybe start to post a complete reproducible code .. e.g. you don't even add the `Start` method etc. A last time: The main issue is you using `new` on a `MonoBehaviour` and all your referenced objects being destroyed the moment you call `LoadScene` ^^

Comment: Yeah, i saw that comment, but thats how we did programm such a thing in java. And this is very logical. I declare a death scene and then call the setup, isn't it.

Comment: Nope .. not if it is a `MonoBehaviour` (or actually `Component`) .. they simply may not exist without being attached to a `GameObject` in the scene. This is Unity ;) Unfortunately they only throw a warning instead of an exception .. nobody knows why since it is simply not valid ^^

Comment: So, how would i call my deathscene then, instead of using             
DeathScreen death = new DeathScreen();
            death.Setup(timeLived.Minute);

i just do 
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/deathScene");

Comment: i indeed hate unity from this point on

Comment: Throwing no error now, but the timeSurvived didn't change :c

Comment: Well where does `timeLivedInSeconds` come from? It is probably stored in the scene which is newly loaded so the value was never set before ;)

Comment: hmm, yeah that worked before with the new DeathScene(). I load the scene, how do i "übergeben/supply?" it a value. Sorry, my english is indeed not the "yellow from the egg"

Comment: if (Health<=0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/deathScene");
        }

Comment: @derHugo Can't really find a way other than the one with the new DeathScene()